# Wireless switch controls Bluetooth - Lenovo Thinkpad - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, keyboard

On Windows the key was intended to control both wireless and Bluetooth but on Ubuntu the switch key when pressed only enables/disables Bluetooth and the wireless network adapter is absent under network settings too.

Comment: Might help if you told the specs of your laptop (including the wireless adapter).

Comment: of course, lenovo thnikpad edge e430 6172-47g
broadcom 802.11 wireless and bluetooth

Comment: resolved, I don’t know exactly how but I reinstalled from live usb with update enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a BIOS setting for the wireless switch. You could choose between "None", "Wifi", "BT", "Wifi & BT". Change it to "Wifi"